# Finding a specific object in state, removing it and replacing it in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My current code finds an object in a `state` array, removes it and then adds a `newValue` in its place. I know using `.splice()` mutates the state directly which is not a recommended practice in React. What is the proper way to do what I am trying to do below?

```
      const found = clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots.find(element => element.timeSlot === timeWithDate);

      if (found) {
        clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots.splice(found, 1)
      }


      const newValue = {
        timeSlot: timeWithDate,
        value: value.value
      }

      setClientServiceReferral({
        ...clientServiceReferral,
        selectedTimeSlots: [...clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots, newValue]
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use map method, which returns a new array, to find and replace:

```
const updatedTimeSlots = clientServiceReferral.selectedTimeSlots.map((element) => {
    if(element.timeSlot === timeWithData){
      return {timeSlot: timeWithDate, value: value.value}
    } else {
      return element
    }
})
setClientServiceReferral({
    ...clientServiceReferral,
    selectedTimeSlots: updatedTimeSlots
})
```

Comment: Won't it be better if you `filter` instead of `map`?

Comment: @Aditya filter is typically used to remove an element by having the callback evaluate to true or false. OP wants to keep all elements and replace one of them. Map works well for this use case. Reduce method is also an option, specifically if OP wanted to transform the accumulator into a different type such as an object.

Comment: @Hyetigran, technically, the goal of filter is not to remove element from array, the goal of filter is to run a test to the array and return data that pass the test

Comment: @James well said